# Add Role to Permission Set for User to see Report

Tags: reporting, permissions, permission-sets, role-hierarchy, roles

I have a user in my org that needs to view a report.
The user used to see the report before he changed role - he is still allowed to see the report but can't as the report is 'role hierarchy' based...

> **How can I let the user see the report even if he isnt in that role anymore?**

I have tried granting him all 'Reports' permissions on permission sets but still not working...

Comment: Try granting access of Report Folder to that user.

Answer (score 1):

> Accessibility of the reports are governed by Folder and not from individual reports.

**Configuration:**

Reach the Reports folder.

Right click the folder and select `Share`.

In the screen, select desired User, Roles etc and respective Access

[image: Report sharing]

Comment: Still not working @Santanu Boral - added his new role and set 'manager' but he still cant see anything in the report like he did last week...

Comment: So, now he can access the report, but he is not able to see the data in the report. is that correct?

Comment: That is correct - There definitely is data in the report, but when we changed his role he can't see it anymore - Its in a public folder and he can access it so not a permissions fix I don't think...